# "NameUser" is currently used by process

Tags: linux

I'm trying to delete `usuario1` with their files. I have create user `usuario1`, it's ok. When I wanted to delete I used `sudo deluser --remove-home Nameuser`. Console says: `usuario1 is currently used by process 8010`. I see that user has not been deleted.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can just kill the reported process pid: `8010` for that user, with:

```
kill -9 8010
```

Then re-run the deluser command.

Your command initially fails because Linux tries to ensure that there will be no running processes with a user that does not exist anymore.